# Control does not exist in current context asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ascx

I have two files: FileGridCS.ascx and FileGridCS.ascx.cs

Within FileGridCS.ascx: I have added the control:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

The header of this file is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FileGridCS.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UserControls_FileGridCS" %>
```

Now, my class FileGridCS.ascx.cs is not recognising 'gvFiles'. I Get the following error:

```
Severity Code   Description  Project          File  Line    Suppression State
Error    CS0103 The name 'gvFiles' does not         137     Active
                exist in the current context
```

What am I doing wrong?, I am a little confused on why this happening when the control exists!

Thanks =)

**UPDATE**

Just to let you know, **my class FileGrid.ascx.cs is a public partial class***

Comment: There's not enough to go on. Please include the full line in the `.cs` file that has `public partial class ...`. Also try removing the gridview and re-adding it (drag it or dbl-click it in the toolbox). Also include all methods that refer to `gvFiles` or explain when/where the error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First You have to Specify the User Control on the .aspx Page**

In which src is Location of that User Control....

In tagName with same name of .ascx in my case UserControl is GridControl.ascx and specify that tagName as GridControl

And also use TagPrefix as your choice...

```
<%@ Register Src="~/App_UserControls/GridControl.ascx" TagName="GridControl" TagPrefix="UC" %>
```

Then use as GridView Like Below Example...

```
<UC:GridControl ID="gvFiles" runat="server" />
```